# Using awk sub function to sequentially number fasta headers

Tags: awk, scripting, bioinformatics

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to sequentially number the headers in a fasta file. The sequences in my fasta file look like this:

```
>Rodentia sp. 
MALWILLPLLALLILWGPDPAQAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYILVCGERGFFYTPMSRREVED
PQVGQVELGAGPGAGSEQTLALEVARQARIVQQCTSGICSLYQENYCN

>Ovis aries
MALWTRLVPLLALLALWAPAPAHAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKARREVEG
PQVGALELAGGPGAGGLEGPPQKRGIVEQCCAGVCSLYQLENYCN
```

I want to use awk in my shell script so that the headers are sequentially numbered, by inserting a number starting from 1 to n (where n is the number of sequences) after the ">", so that the sequences look like this:

```
> 1 Rodentia sp. 
MALWILLPLLALLILWGPDPAQAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYILVCGERGFFYTPMSRREVED
PQVGQVELGAGPGAGSEQTLALEVARQARIVQQCTSGICSLYQENYCN

> 2 Ovis aries
MALWTRLVPLLALLALWAPAPAHAFVNQHLCGSHLVEALYLVCGERGFFYTPKARREVEG
PQVGALELAGGPGAGGLEGPPQKRGIVEQCCAGVCSLYQLENYCN
```

I tried using the sub function in awk, to do this, replacing every instance of ">" with "> [a number]".

```
awk '/>/{sub(">", "> ++i ")}1' file
```

However, I don't understand how to increment variables using the sub function in awk. I would like to know if there is a way to do this using the sub function. I understand how sub works, but I don't know how to declare the variable to be incremented properly.

I declared i to be 1 at the beginning of my shell script:

```
i=1
```

However, the output I get from the sub function is:

```
> ++$i Rodentia sp. 
> ++$i Ovis aries
```

How can a declare a variable properly so that I can use the awk sub function to number the headers?

Comment: You are also new to this site, so please be so polite to read at least the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, just take `++i` outside of quoted substring `"> ++i"` to `"> " ++i`.

```
awk '/^>/{sub(">", "> "++i " ")}1' infile
```

Comment: What is the reason for having to place ++i within its own set of quotation marks so that the expression is "> "++i" "?

Comment: Hi, no `++i` is outside of two quoted strings, between `">" [++i HERE]  " "`, the last `" "` is just a space.

Answer (score 0):

[As αғsнιη pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395292/116858), you're inserting `++i` as part of a literal string.

An alternative solution, which may look a bit prettier:

```
awk -F '>' '/^>/ { $1 = "> " ++i } { print }' file.fa
```

or, if you like the shorthand for `{ print }`,

```
awk -F '>' '/^>/ { $1 = "> " ++i } 1' file.fa
```

This uses `>` as the input field delimiter and replaces the first field (the bit before the `>`, which is empty in the input) on any header line with the required string.

Comment: I know that $1 is the variable in which the first command line argument a user passes in is stored. In the context of awk, what does the $1 mean?

Comment: @ceno980 `$1` in an `awk` program is the first field (column) of the current record (line). `$2` will be the second, and so on. `NF` is the number of fields in the current record and `$NF` is thus the value of the _last_ field.